# Who sets RAILS_MAX_THREADS environment variable when running Puma or Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Who sets RAILS_MAX_THREADS environment variable when running Puma or Passenger on Linux?

How can I query the value of RAILS_MAX_THREADS from the linux command line while Puma or Passenger is running?

Comment: If you didn't set these env variables in your start scripts they are probably not set on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's our responsibility to set `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` environment variable, that's why in most of the places it's written as

```
<%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

Means, if the constant is defined, then take that value, or use `5` by default. You can set it while running the deployment script, e.g.,

```
export RAILS_MAX_THREADS=10
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The name RAILS_MAX_THREADS got me confused, as it sounds like something set automatically by Rails. Much better if they just named it RAILS_DB_POOL_SIZE.

Comment: @BasilMusa They can't name it RAILS_DB_POOL_SIZE because they use the RAILS_MAX_THREADS in puma configuration as well, check `puma.rb`

Comment: Do you have a link on how puma.rb uses this?